# Ubuntu won't boot: no irq handler for vector

Tags: boot

I had been using Manjaro for almost a year, but suddenly one day it started showing a lot of 'audit' messages on the second screen, you know, that 'no irq handler for vector' thing, and just stuck there. It only booted properly after 15-20 attempts. I had seen somewhere that Arch-based distros are known for their sudden issues, so I decided to install PopOS.

The Live USB also kept showing those audit messages along with the [OK] messages and didn't move ahead. I tried multiple USB drives multiple times on different ports. It just didn't work. Then I started getting bad feelings for Linux and installed Windows 7, as well as to see if it's only Linux that's being problematic, and Windows got installed without a problem.

However, I didn't want Windows, so I decided to install Ubuntu, because it's quite established and is known for its stability. Ubuntu got installed, worked fine for a few days, and I was really enjoying the interface, but then again, it too started showing those 'audit' messages instead of booting normally.

I haven't been able to get it to boot after numerous attempts. It's hard to keep a backup of my data because it becomes quite large, and I need my laptop for daily use. I don't want to go back to Windows, so please somebody help me. I said it's a unique issue because I tried googling, but to no avail. Please don't let my love for Linux die.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, on an HP Pavilion G6, with AMD Radeon Graphics, and an AMD A8 processor

Comment: HI Kadar!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  It sounds like you may be having a hardware issue that's not specific to Ubuntu.  Are you able to upload a photo of the messages you're getting?  If you can't, can you be more specific as to the wording of these "Audit" messages.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, on an HP Pavilion G6, with AMD Radeon Graphics, and an AMD A8 processor.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see an option to upload a picture here.

Comment: The kernels are 5.8 and 5.11 as it shows under Advanced Options for Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there any way I can disable audit using GRUB command line?

Comment: You currently don't have enough *rep* to upload pictures, however you can provide URLs where pictures can be viewed.  You didn't say if desktop or server, but 5.8 & 5.11 imply you're using the HWE stack option with 20.04; if the 5.8 kernel works, the easiest work-around will be switching to the GA kernel stack (ie. return to 5.4 which is supported the entire life of 20.04). ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and search for the "*To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel: *" section.  You don't need to remove HWE as both stacks can exist on your system (select at grub)

Answer (score 0):

It probably was a hardware issue. I thoroughly cleaned the RAM ports and HDD ports, and apparently the problem seems to have been solved for the moment.

Comment: It's started happening again; clearing the ports doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I was over this same issue for 3 days, formatting and reformatting with no progress.

I will suggest installing the ubuntu from a live usb using the OEM manufacturers option. It should boot successfully and you can do all needful setting afterwards